How are (NetBIOS?) names being resolved on my network?
Firstly, i have little understanding of Windows Network Discovery, and how NetBIOS operates. I don't like it, and i try to ignore it. I have a server on my LAN, which (among other things) is acting as a file and print server (SMB) for clients on the LAN.
When I set this up, since I wanted fine control over open ports etc (Even though this is just a home setup), instead of enabling file and printer sharing in Control Panel, I left this disabled and made a firewall rule allowing port 445 inbound, for SMB. This worked great, i had a functioning fileserver, with only port 445 open (Not 137,139, etc).
Just recently I have set this same machine up to share a USB printer over the network. Initially, I thought this would work just fine over port 445, already in use by SMB, but I have just discovered port 135 is open too, (RPC?), and closing this breaks printing. Obviously 135 is needed for printing.
The Problem:  I have just noticed that in my router/firewall interface, I can see the name of my server machine. Call it HOMESERVER as an example. This made me wonder, how does the router find out the name of the machine? I am sure that before, the router didn't show the machine name, only the IP (Which is the case with my PC, which has network discovery etc off), so I am unsure what's changed. Typing \\HOMESERVER\ into Windows Explorer on my PC prompts me for login credentials, so somehow this name is being resolved to the IP of the server. Additionally, typing \\MY-PC-NAME\ into Explorer on the server resolves to the IP of my PC.
My question is, how are NetBIOS names being resolved on my network? What ports and services are being used? What I really want to do is block all of this, so all kinds of 'Network Discovery' is off, and only specific ports are open / services available (Such as SMB). I have no use for NetBIOS names, and will use DNS to resolve host names if needed. Despite not being a huge issue, I dislike not knowing what is going on here and would like to learn more!
EDIT: Fired up Wireshark and discovered a lot of UDP broadcast packets labeled 'NBNS' (NetBIOS Name Service?) flying around the place on port 137. I observed that if i cleared the NetBIOS cache on my PC (nbtstat /R), and then tried to access \\HOMESERVER\, a UDP broadcast was sent querying HOMESERVER. My server responded to the broadcast with its IP Address. I then tried creating a firewall rule specifically blocking UDP 137 inbound on my server (Although I thought there was no rule ALLOWING this, and the firewall is set to default block, which is strange), and now when repeating the above test, a query is sent, and the server does not respond. (Because the incoming packet was blocked by the server's firewall). However, SOMEHOW, my PC was able to resolve \\HOMESERVER\ to an IP and attempt to connect. (Although it has not added the IP to the NetBIOS cache this time).
How did it manage this?
EDIT 2 (In response to answer below):

Generally NetBIOS is tied to SMBv1 being enabled; if SMBv1 is disabled at OS level, then NetBIOS features are not used at all.

This is interesting, as I have SMBv1 disabled in Windows on both machines, (appwiz.cpl > Turn Windows features on or off), however Wireshark is definitely showing UDP traffic on port 137, marked as 'NBNS'. Not sure why this is...

In most cases it learns that from your DHCP lease request. Although I've had a router that monitored NetBIOS name announcements as well, but that's rare in comparison whereas the usage of DHCP to build up the router's internal hostname list is near universal with home equipment.

This could definitely be the case, although my server has a static IPv4 address, so DHCP is not used here. IPv6 is obtained automatically. The reason i thought this might be something to do with some kind of network discovery is that until recently, the router didn't seem to know the name of my PC, my server (Both had network discovery switched off), or my IP camera and NVR box, which i doubt support any discovery protocols. I did however know the names of other PC's on the network which likely had all the discovery stuff etc switched on. Just recently i noticed the name of my server appeared, and wondered why.
I suppose the question is, at this point, is there anywhere in Windows where i can disable all of these (in this case, probably useless) protocols such as mDNS, LLMNR, NetBIOS, etc, or must I manually block ports like 5353 & 5355 in my firewall?

Your router may be set to support NetBIOS over TCP/IP .


Firstly, i have little understanding of Windows Network Discovery, and how NetBIOS operates. I don't like it, and i try to ignore it.

Mostly, NetBIOS doesn't operate anymore. You only have remnants of NetBIOS these days, and then only if you have enabled SMBv1 support on Windows (or the nmbd service on Samba) – otherwise the NetBIOS-based "computer browsing" is disabled (replaced by WS-Discovery), the NetBIOS "name service" is also disabled (replaced by DNS/mDNS/LLMNR), etc.

Just recently I have set this same machine up to share a USB printer over the network. Initially, I thought this would work just fine over port 445, already in use by SMB, but I have just discovered port 135 is open too, (RPC?), and closing this breaks printing. Obviously 135 is needed for printing.

"Old style" printing worked entirely through special SMB shares; "NT style" printing works through MS-RPC. Now that can be transported via SMB 'named pipes' as well as directly via TCP (and it's highly inconsistent as to which RPC-based services will use SMB and which use TCP), but I seem to remember printing was recently moved to use raw TCP in order to mitigate several attacks that were made possible by the SMB usage.
It is better to use the per-service rules within Windows Firewall than port-based rules, as it is able to restrict access to individual RPC services even if they share the same port (and even if they're being accessed through SMB).

The Problem: I have just noticed that in my router/firewall interface, I can see the name of my server machine. Call it HOMESERVER as an example. This made me wonder, how does the router find out the name of the machine?

In most cases it learns that from your DHCP lease request. Although I've had a router that monitored NetBIOS name announcements as well, but that's rare in comparison whereas the usage of DHCP to build up the router's internal hostname list is near universal with home equipment.

Typing \HOMESERVER\ into Windows Explorer on my PC prompts me for login credentials, so somehow this name is being resolved to the IP of the server.

That might be NetBIOS name service (UDP 137) as you suggest, but it might also be more modern alternatives – mDNS (UDP 5353) or LLMNR (UDP 5355).
Generally NetBIOS is tied to SMBv1 being enabled; if SMBv1 is disabled at OS level, then NetBIOS features are not used at all. Microsoft tried to replace the NetBIOS name service with LLMNR at first but now is settling on the more universal mDNS (which many other systems support).
It could also be unicast DNS, with your router's internal DNS server building up a list from the DHCP leases as mentioned earlier.
